# ¿como usar estimateEnergy de tronweb?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, criptografía

intento calcular la transferencia de un token en la red TRC20 (Tron) y no logro estimar la energía que costara esa transacción

```
const eenergy = await window.tronWeb.transactionBuilder.estimateEnergy(window.tronWeb.address.toHex("XXXXXXXXXX"), window.tronWeb.sha3("transfer(address,uint256)",false), {}, ["XXXXXXXXXXX","1000000"], window.tronWeb.address.toHex(this.props.accountAddress));

console.log(eenergy)
```